# selenium - Can't work out how to get FireFox WebDriver to work

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox

This should be easy, but I'm missing something. I'm just trying to get some selenium python tests running on firefox, which work perfectly in chrome.

The problem is just trying to get the ff webdriver up and running!

I have the following code, all the paths are correct:

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
geckopath = 'C:\source\web_deploy_tests\geckodriver.exe'
browser = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(
    capabilities={},
    executable_path=geckopath,
    firefox_profile=profile,
    firefox_binary=binary
)
browser.get("http://google.com")
```

I'm using Python 3.6.2, selenium 3.6.0 and have v0.19.0 of geckodriver.exe and FF is v56.0.1.

When I run the above code, firefox appears but just sits there for about 30 secs then crashes with:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the
>   profile. Possible firefox version mismatch. You must use GeckoDriver
>   instead for Firefox 48+. Profile Dir:
>   C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3\tmpkx5dau8h If you specified a
>   log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

I've tried various combinations of args but I am failing.

Any ideas? 
TIA

Answer (score -1):

I got it working by passing in DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
geckopath = 'C:\source\web_deploy_tests\geckodriver.exe'
browser = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(
    capabilities=**DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX**,
    executable_path=geckopath,
    firefox_profile=profile,
    firefox_binary=binary
)
browser.get("http://google.com")
```

Now I can at least bring up the browser window!

Comment: This is an answer. Why do you think it works by passing that? What happens after the windows pop up?